# no operator "/" matches these operands

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

trying to make player shoot 360
is there something wrong or misspelled?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>



using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "360 shooting object");

    CircleShape circle(25.f);
    circle.setFillColor(Color::White);

    Vector2f circleCenter;
    Vector2f mousePosWindow;
    Vector2f aimDirection;
    Vector2f aimDirectionNorm;

    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type==Event::Closed) window.close();
            if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) window.close();
        }

        draw(window, circle);

        update(window, circle, circleCenter, mousePosWindow, aimDirection, aimDirectionNorm);

    }
    return 0;
}

void update(RenderWindow &window, CircleShape &shape, Vector2f circleCenter, 
    Vector2f mousePosWindow, Vector2f aimDirection, Vector2f aimDirectionNorm)
{
    circleCenter = Vector2f(shape.getPosition().x + shape.getRadius(), 
        shape.getPosition().y + shape.getRadius());
    mousePosWindow = Vector2f(Mouse::getPosition(window));
    aimDirection = mousePosWindow - circleCenter;
    aimDirectionNorm = aimDirection / sqrt(pow(aimDirection.x, 2)) + sqrt(pow(aimDirection.y, 2));
```

}

im using sfml
error at the aimDirectionNorm part
no operator matches the '/' operand
what wrong with the '/' operator i don't understand

i delete some code i

Comment: `Vector2f` is a vector of float while `sqrt` return double... try to cast to float

Comment: Unrelated, but this is not correct formula 2-norm if you are going for that. `sqrt`,`pow` cancel each other out so they are useless as written right now. Also you likely want divide by both terms, not just the first.

Comment: What is the type of aimDirection, does that vector type have an overload for division by a double?

Comment: The correct forumla should be `aimDirectionNorm = aimDirection / (sqrt(pow(aimDirection.x, 2) + pow(aimDirection.y, 2)));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your math is wrong

```
aimDirectionNorm = aimDirection / sqrt(pow(aimDirection.x, 2)) + 
    sqrt(pow(aimDirection.y, 2));
```

should be

```
aimDirectionNorm = aimDirection / sqrt(pow(aimDirection.x, 2) + 
    pow(aimDirection.y, 2));
```

Secondly `operator/` requires a `Vector2f` and a `float` but `sqrt` returns a `double`. Because `Vector2f` is a template the normal `double` to `float` conversion does not happen.

Simple way to get a `float` would be to use `sqrtf` and `powf`

```
aimDirectionNorm = aimDirection / sqrtf(powf(aimDirection.x, 2) + 
    powf(aimDirection.y, 2));
```